# What are the parts of google adwords url?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I need to automatically generate url to the existing advertisement in google adwords. I've got a link like this:

> https://adwords.google.com/cm/CampaignMgmt?authuser=1&__u=%param_one%&__c=%param_two%#c.%param_three%.create&app=cm

I do not know what are those params one, two, and three. I do not know where can I get them and what is their role in an address. But I'd like to! In fact I just need to generate a URL to click on it and appear on an ad page. How can that be done? May be their [lib](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/clientlibraries) provides a method to generate url like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible, at least not in a reliable way (see also [this rather old post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/j22Tnb-eetM/y-gXG-OLerQJ) from the Adwords API forum).

The structure itself is not hard to parse:

- Inside the query string, `__u` is your user account's ID while `__c` refers to the ID of the specific Adwords account. These don't appear to be in standard Adwords `XXX-XXX-XXXX` format, though, so you would have to either create a mapping of all your accounts or come up with the proper translation function.
- The fragment refers to a specific Adwords entity, for instance; `c.123` is the campaign with ID `123` while `a.ABC_XYZ` refers to the adgroup with ID `ABC` inside the campaign with ID `XYZ`.

But even if you manage to get the `__u` and `__c` parameters right, more often than not you will be redirected to your Adwords account's top level view.

Interestingly enough, Google Analytics introduced little buttons in the "Adwords" reporting tab a few months ago which are supposed to take you right to the correct campaign if you have access to the linked account, but even those only work half of the time, especially if your Adwords account is an MCC.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot)